# How do I correctly persist a Powershell object to JSON when the object was added using Add-Member to a child item?

Tags: json, powershell

I'm running into a bit of a challenge with some PowerShell code, a simplified and sanitized version of which is shown here:

```
$outer = ("{""Child"": {""Grandchild"": {}}}" | ConvertFrom-Json )
$inner = $outer.Child.Grandchild
$newId = [guid]::NewGuid();
$nested = ("{
    ""Id"": ""$newId"",
    ""Name"": ""The Name Goes Here""
}" | ConvertFrom-Json)

$memberNameToAdd = "Nested"
$inner | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $memberNameToAdd $nested

$inner | ConvertTo-Json | Out-file "inner.json"
$outer | ConvertTo-Json | Out-file "outer.json"
```

My specific challenge is with the way the dynamically added inner item is getting persisted. The output from $inner (as sent to inner.json) matches what I expect:

```
{
    "Nested":  {
        "Id":  "741b6810-000e-4461-8ab8-6573e0d0b4a7",
        "Name":  "The Name Goes Here"
        }
}
```

Unfortunately the output from $outer is serialized as follows:

```
{
    "Child":  {
        "Grandchild":  {
            "Nested":  "@{Id=741b6810-000e-4461-8ab8-6573e0d0b4a7; Name=The Name Goes Here}"
         }
    }
}
```

Clearly this results in a situation where when serialized back from the file (using ConvertFrom-Json) I can no longer access the properties of "Nested".

What have I done wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickly your problem should come from the default `depth` type :

```
$inner | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 6 | Out-file "inner.json"
$outer | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 6| Out-file "outer.json"
```

In fact by default it stop parsing in Depth 3, after it gives you the `ToString()` value of the object.

Comment: Sure enough, adding a Depth parameter was all I needed. Thanks!